# image attachment to a mail.. how in android?

Tags: android, email, android-sdcard, android-gallery

i can pick a image and its path using intent. with the use of that path of an image. i have to set that image as attachment of the mail's body content. how its possible in android???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.emlSendToFriendSubject));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{emailto});
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getResources().getString(R.string.emlSendToFriendBody));
File file = getFileStreamPath(EMAIL_TEMP_FILE);
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.btnSendToFriend)),ActMain.EMAIL_DONE);
```

Comment: it is a constant defined by me that I check for in onActivityResult.  you can also use startActivity() instead if you don't care if the user canceled the 'pick app' popup (the OS popup listing all compatible apps).