# How to send an image as an e-mail attachment in android using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I wanted to send an image as an e-mail attachment in android.
     Is there any PhoneGap plugin available to do this ... If not please suggest me how to proceed in implementing the plugin for the email with image attachment.
 any help is highly appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see such a [PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android), but it's easy to implement in Android, here's a [stackoverflow article on doing that in Android Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518055/image-attachment-to-a-mail-how-in-android)...

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Leon thnx for the link it helped,
it opens an email client i enter the details there and when i click send , it displays "sending..." but it neva sends.

Comment: what's your `adb logcat` output?

Comment: the logcat shows no errors ... it is showing a gmail warning which is : " WARN/GTalkService(179): [GTalkConnection.18] doConnect: caught XMPPError connecting to mtalk.google.com:5228."

Comment: Leon it worked on the actual device ....
But what if the image is in the /res/drawable folder how to provide the URL of the image which is in the project folder itself .... ???

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [EmailComposer](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/EmailComposerWithAttachments). However, it might not be plugman compatible, required since PhoneGap 3.0, but somebody might have fixed one up on a personal repository. If you're working in an earlier version of PhoneGap this isn't an issue.