# Sending image by email, Android?

Tags: android, image, email, bitmap

I'm trying to make an application to capture an image and send it by email, I successfully made it by the following code

```
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp,"title", null);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent
            .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddresses);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using"));
```

But the image is sent in a small size and very low resolution ?! Any suggestions for sending the image with it's actual size and resolution ?! Or is there any other way to get a jpeg image from the camera result instead of a bitmap ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518055/image-attachment-to-a-mail-how-in-android

Answer (score 0):

`bmp` is a Bitmap I assume? Then you can save the image by use the compress http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29 method from the bitmap class to write it to a file, and then create a Uri from the file.

When you insert an image, the Uri you receive from Media can be a reduced version.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EMAIL_SUBJECT);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, EMAIL_TEXT);
File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), IMAGE_PATH);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(newFile));
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: the path of the image because the stream take the uri of the file path