# Issue with uploading an image email attachment for Android

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

For one of my projects, I'm trying to simply attach an image to an email and send it.

```
         Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         emailIntent.setType("image/jpg");
         emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
         "Image attached.");
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filePath));
         emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
         "Send email using.."));
```

My variable "filePath" is the absolute file path of an image found on the external storage of my device. It's in the form of "/mnt/sdcard/....." The path to my image is definitely correct because I am successfully loading photos into other image views.

This intent also works fine, and is able to bring me to a screen to select an application to use to send my image. HOWEVER, in the actual email, I can see that my image has been attached (the file path name is 100% correct), but the image itself does not get attached.

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be the cause to this problem?

Comment: Look this It might help you to solve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518055/image-attachment-to-a-mail-how-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File fileToAttach = new File(filePath, filename);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fileToAttach));
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Worked for me. My problem was that I was getting it from the file as string and took `file://` instead of `file:///`. Setting it as a `File` object instead of a `String` solved everything. Interesting thing was that it worked while previewing the file and sending it to Evernote, but broke when trying to email through the Gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

Also getting the same problem

**Code**:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] 
    {"me@gmail.com"}); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, 
    "Test Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
    "go on read the emails"); 
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "sPhotoUri=" + Uri.parse("file:/"+ sPhotoFileName));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+ sPhotoFileName));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

**From adb logcat**:

```
V/DumbDumpersMain( 3972):   sPhotoUri=file://sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
I/ActivityManager(   56):   Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.CHOOSER comp={android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity} (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   56):   Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.SEND type=jpeg/image flags=0x3000000 comp={com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail} (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   56):   Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.SEND type=jpeg/image flags=0x2800000 comp={com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivity} (has extras) }
D/gmail-ls(  120):      MailProvider.query: content://gmail-ls/labels/me@gmail.com(null, null)
D/Gmail   ( 2507):      URI FOUND:file://sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
```

Looks like the email provider is attaching a 0 length file. When I check the filesystem the file is there and correct. The code which creates the image file is well finished prior to the attempt to email it.

Anyone fixed this without magic reboots (I've already tried that)?

**Update**

Path for me should have been

```
file:///sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
```

you need the extra / as this points to the root directory, i.e.:

```
file:// + /sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
```

combined as

```
file:///sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
```

In the above snippet you need:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+ sPhotoFileName));
```

I hope this helps. It took me ages to debug.

Comment: hey Dixit, thanks. I tried your approach, and my final path is in the same exact format as the filepath you listed above. BUT the image still doesn't get attached but the file is definitely there and the path is definitely correct :(

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

```
File pngDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"DCIM/Camera");  
File pngfile = new File(pngDir, "<ImageName>");  
Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(pngfile);  
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("image/*");  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"<Email>");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"<Subject>");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"<Message>");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,pngUri);
emailIntent.setType("image/png");  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Video");
           sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+path));
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the Video");
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"))
```