# how to attach image in email in android

Tags: android, email-attachments

How to attach image in email? I am able to attach text in email but not attach image properly,
      so only send the Text but not send the Image.

Problem with,

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
```

so Control direct put in catch statement after urlConnection.connect();, Image not save in SDACRD.so not attach the image. How to do?

```
  My code in Below,
urlShare = "http://example.com/share.php?id="+ strId;

public class sendImageThroughEmail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        /** Hashmap for Share */
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrDataList = null;

        String strMessage = null, strImageLocator = null;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String filePath, strImageName;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            arrDataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlShare);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    strMessage = jsonobject.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    strImageLocator = jsonobject.getString(TAG_DATA);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strImageLocator);
                //URL url = new URL("http://example.com/upload/images (8).jpg");

                strImageName = strImageLocator.substring(strImageLocator
                        .lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();

                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsoluteFile();
                String filename = strImageName;
                Log.i("Local File:", filename);
                File file = new File(SDCardRoot, filename);
                if (file.createNewFile()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                int downloadedSize = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    Log.i("Progress:", "downloadSize:" + downloadedSize
                            + "totalSize:" + totalSize);
                }
                fileOutput.close();
                if (downloadedSize == totalSize) {
                    filePath = file.getPath();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsoluteFile();
            String filename = strImageName;
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot, filename);
            Uri markPath = Uri.fromFile(file);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, markPath);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strMessage);
            email.setType("image/png");
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email Client"));
        }
    };
```

My ImageLocator Like this,
1) http://example.com/upload/images (8).jpg
2) http://example.com/upload/11_2134_232222_33.png
Please Guide me.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can either have `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`, not both, and the `setType()` call has to match whichever one of those that you use.

Comment: @CommonsWare But It's not Issues. Issues is  Control put in urlConnection.connect(); then after directly catch statements.

Comment: @CommonsWare means It is not attach. and not save image in sdcard.

Comment: Then perhaps you could LogCat to see what your problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: `email.setType("image/png");
            email.setType("message/rfc822");` are sequentially destructive. The second call cancels the first.

Comment: `url
                        .openConnection()` you can't do that in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit following strings in your email intent:

```
//...
email.setType("image/jpeg");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()));
//...
```

For more info you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518055/image-attachment-to-a-mail-how-in-android).

**EDIT**

To download file use this code:

```
private final static String SD_CARD = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
private final static String PNG = ".png";
private final static String APP_FOLDER = "Folder Name";

/**
 * Checking if the SD card is mounted
 * 
 * @return SD card existence
 */
public static boolean isSdPresent()
{
    return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}

/**
 * Downloads image file onto SD card in specific folder
 * 
 * @param fileUrl URL for downloading of file
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static void downloadImage(String fileUrl) throws IOException
{
    if (isSdPresent())
    {
        if (fileUrl.length() > 0)
        {
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            InputStream input = url.openStream();

            File folder = new File(SD_CARD, APP_FOLDER);
            if (!folder.exists())
                folder.mkdir();

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder,
                    fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.indexOf("=") + 1, fileUrl.length())
                            + PNG));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0)
            {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.e("SD card", "not mounted");
    }
}
```

Comment: what makes you think `Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath())` is better than `Uri.fromFile(file);`?

Comment: @njzk2 Hello  My control put urlConnection.connect(); then after Directly put in catch statement. means it is not save the image in sdcard. how to do for save image in sdcard and then after attach image in email?

Comment: @Artyom Kiriliyk Now not attach the image because image not save in sdcard. Please see my updated Question.